# POSIX Async Safety Linter for C/C++

Tags: c, signals, posix

I'm trying to understand if there are some simple ways to add some basic lints for async safety into a codebase.  The idea was to keep a list of safe functions to call somewhere and then use clang analyzer's call graph output to see if async safety is violated.

However it seems really cumbersome to actually do that and I'm wondering if there are already existing tools to facilitate that.  Ideally by being able to annotate the function itself with something like `__attribute__(annotate("async-safe"))` if a function is async-safe despite it not appearing as such on the surface.